# Implementar un def dentro de un if [PYTHON]

Tags: python

Hola esta es la "parte 2" de mi duda,lo que quiero hacer es que el usuario cuando ingrese "1" se ejecute ese scrip,primero les pasare el codigo donde esta el if

```
eligio = raw_input("""

1)Extraccion de html

2)otro

3)otro

Elige :><: """)

if eligio =="1": #Aqui es donde empezaria el otro codigo
```

Despues de ese if quiero que venga el siguiente codigo que extrae el html de una pagina

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time, urllib2
import os
import sys
def html(link): # Definimos  
    try:
        res = urllib2.Request(link)
        return urllib2.urlopen(res).read()

    except Exception, e:
        print """Error    """
        time.sleep(3)
        os.system("rm" + " " +name_of_files)
        os.system("clear")
        return ''

os.system("clear")
http = "http://"
link = http+raw_input(""" Ingresa la url sin http : """)
os.system("clear")

name_of_files = raw_input(""" Ingresa el nombre del archivo mas su  extension : """)
archivo = open(name_of_files, "a+") 
archivo.write(html(link))
```

Como en la pregunta anterior me dijieron que llamara a la funcion def, lo hice pero me marco este error

**File "Web_T.py", line 20, in html html(1) RuntimeError: maximum recursion** **depth exceeded **

Tambien me explicaron ese error, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se como lo estas implementando pero no debería dar problemas simplemente incrustando el código dentro del condicional, el siguiente código funciona perfectamente pasandole el link de esta misma pregunta:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time, urllib2
import os
import sys


eligio = raw_input("""

1)Extraccion de html

2)otro

3)otro

Elige :><: """)

if eligio =="1":
    def html(link): # Definimos
        try:
            res = urllib2.Request(link)
            return urllib2.urlopen(res).read()

        except Exception, e:
            print """Error    """
            time.sleep(3)
            os.system("rm" + " " +name_of_files)
            os.system("clear")
            return ''

    os.system("clear")
    http = "http://"
    link = http+raw_input(""" Ingresa la url sin http : """)
    os.system("clear")

    name_of_files = raw_input(""" Ingresa el nombre del archivo mas su  extension : """)
    archivo = open(name_of_files, "a+")
    archivo.write(html(link))

elif eligio == '2':
    pass
elif eligio == '3':
    pass
```

Prueba a ver si te genera algún error.

Comment: Muchas gracias, probare con los demas ^^

Answer (score 2):

Si vas a ocupar el metodo de cualquier manera ¿por qué simplemente no lo llamas cuando el usuario escoge 1? 
 De cualquier manera al cargar el script se va a generar el metodo solo que sera utilizado si es que es necesario.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time, urllib2
import os
import sys

def html(link): # Definimos
    try:
        res = urllib2.Request(link)
        return urllib2.urlopen(res).read()
    except Exception, e:
        print """Error    """
        time.sleep(3)
        os.system("rm" + " " +name_of_files)
        os.system("clear")
        return ''


eligio = raw_input("""

1)Extraccion de html

2)otro

3)otro

Elige :><: """)



if eligio =="1":
    os.system("clear")
    http = "http://"
    link = http+raw_input(""" Ingresa la url sin http : """)
    os.system("clear")

    name_of_files = raw_input(""" Ingresa el nombre del archivo mas su  extension : """)
    archivo = open(name_of_files, "a+")
    archivo.write(html(link))

elif eligio == '2':
    pass
elif eligio == '3':
    pass
```